# How to get child of child in firebase?

Tags: android, firebase

I need use this code to get this nameID

```
requests.orderByChild("doctor").orderByChild("nameID").equalTo(id)
```

but I can't use this because it can't use 2 (orderByChild) at once

[image]

Comment: Please try and add to your question what the image linked as `example` depicts.

Comment: This is my database tables in firebase.

Comment: You want to get the value of nameID only from one request or from all requests?

Comment: Just one request... Nvm i tried and tried and got it by myself at the end... Its so easy.. We just should get (all the path) and call it in the func... Like this ("doctor/0/nameID")